# Tuning advices?

Tags: 14.04, unity, ram

I'm new to Ubuntu, running 14.04 and I realize how could I get some more speed with 2GB of RAM.

If someone could bring some fine tuning advices just to speed things up a quite bit would be great.

Comment: If all you need is a command line, go ahead and uninstall Unity. Otherwise, find a desktop environment that requires less resources: start [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-kinds-of-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I would like to have a GUI for my family to use it. I can try installing other windows managers. Anyway I'll wait for other replies, maybe they have other tun(n?)ing ideas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity is the name of the default Ubuntu Desktop, known by its vertical buttons on the left etc.

It is possible to replace this desktop, but if you are really new, it might be easier to just reinstall a different Ubuntu flavor such as Xubuntu or Lubuntu.

Also consider the Ubuntu derivative Linux Mint, installing Linux Mint from scratch might be the easiest path, it is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with a different desktop (called Cinnamon).

These other desktops tend to look more like a classic windows desktop, But Unity and Gnome3 do things differently, more "tablet" oriented.

But you can still test desktops in your current install, by installing a package name with -desktop at the end. From the Software Center, you search say, lubuntu-desktop, install that and then log out; before logging back in there is an option to change the desktop to Lubuntu (LXDE).

The disadvantage of this is that you end with redundant packages from both desktops taking more space and memory, as opposed to having a fresh Lubuntu install from its own iso.

Also if you will never have more than 2gb of ram in that computer, stick to 32bit edition, is needs less ram than 64bit.